# Microsoft PKI (ADCS)

Tags: private-key

“PKI infra will be built on domain “hgb.hs.int” which is internal and not routable over internet. So, the CRL URL would be http://crl.abc.int (accessible only from internal).
“abc.co.uk” is the domain routable over internet, question is How can we publish the CRL over internet? Can we host and publish the CRL using http://crl.abc.co.uk in the DMZ vNet which can be accessed by both intranet and internet users? “